# Why we suppose the numbers in Arithmetic Sequence like this?

Tags: sequences-and-series

I want to know why we suppose the numbers in A.P as **a-d,a,a+d**
And if we want to suppose that five numbers are equal to some value, then we suppose as **a-2d,a-d,a,a+d,a-2d** and for four numbers we suppose **a-3d,a-d,a+d,a+3d**
Why we suppose the numbers of an A.P like this, why not like **a,a+d,a+2d** and vice versa?

Comment: A.P? What does that mean?

Comment: A.P. means "arithmetic progression".

Answer (score 1):

We may assume any of these that we like; $$a-2d, a-d, a, a+d, a-2d$$ or $$a, a+d, a+2d, a+3d, a+4d$$

The benefit of the first is perhaps that some calculations will be simpler.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there's a standard way to denote the numbers in an arithmetic progression. Either convention can be chosen according to taste or uselfuness for a particular problem.

For instance, if you wanted to compute the sum of a number of consecutive numbers in an arithmetic progression using young Gauss' trick, writing it as
$$
a+(a+d)+(a+2d)\cdots+(a+kd)=\frac{(k+1)(2a+kd)}{2}
$$
looks nicer.

Comment: Then how to solve this question:

Comment: Q: Find the three numbers in A.P whose sum is 15 and the product is 45? If i suppose a,a+d,a+2d.. it doesn't work.

Comment: Why not? $a+(a+d)+(a+2d)=15$ implies $a+d=5$ and then $a(a+d)(a+2d)=5(25-d^2)=45$ implies $d=\pm4$, so that you have the two solutions $(a=1,d=4)$ or $(a=9,d=-4)$.

Comment: Ok if a+d replaced by 5 and a replaced by 5-d then how this 5(25-d^2) came. Can you please explain that how you have done with simplification?

Comment: @zonnie: It is simple arithmetic after the substituition $a=5-d$, you should really be able to reconstruct it yourself.

Comment: Oh yes.. I have done with this.. Thanks a billions Andrea Mori.